# How to use spinner and then display a component after submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am building this project using ChakraUI and ReactJS.
So in this UploadImage component, what I wanna do is, when you choose a file and then hit the Upload button, the spinner will load while the data is being fetched. After it is finished fetching the data, the loading is going to be false and it will render the  component.
But currently it is rendering  component initially and after you submit the file it renders the DisplayImage component.
So how to implement the spinner component properly?

My current code is the following:

```
function UploadImage() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [inputImage, setInputImage] = useState(null);
  const [outputImage, setOutputImage] = useState(null);
  const [isSubmit, setIsubmit] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
  const fileUploadHandler = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
    axios
      .post(`/api/predict`, fd)
      .then((res) => {
        setIsubmit(true);
        setInputImage(res.data.image);
        setOutputImage(res.data.mask);
        selectedFile(null);
        setError(null);
        setIsloading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setError(error.data);
      });
  };

  const fileData = () => {
    if (selectedFile) {
      if (
        selectedFile.type === "image/jpeg" ||
        selectedFile.type === "image/png"
      ) {
        return (
          <div>
            {error && <div>file too large!!</div>}
            <Button
              colorScheme='teal'
              size='sm'
              onClick={() => fileUploadHandler()}
            >
              Upload!
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div>
            <h4>Please choose an image to upload</h4>
          </div>
        );
      }
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h4>Choose Photos</h4>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='file' onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])} />
      {fileData()}
      {isSubmit && isLoading === false ? (
        <DisplayImage inputImage={inputImage} outputImage={outputImage} />
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default UploadImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function UploadImage() {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [inputImage, setInputImage] = useState(null);
    const [outputImage, setOutputImage] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(false);

    const fileUploadHandler = () => {
        setIsloading(true);
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
        axios
            .post(`/api/predict`, fd)
            .then((res) => {
                setInputImage(res.data.image);
                setOutputImage(res.data.mask);
                selectedFile(null);
                setError(null);
                setIsloading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                setSelectedFile(null);
                setError(error.data);
                setIsloading(false);
            });
    };

    const fileData = () => {
        if (selectedFile) {
            if (
                selectedFile.type === "image/jpeg" ||
                selectedFile.type === "image/png"
            ) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {
                            error ? <div>file too large!!</div> :
                                <Button
                                    colorScheme='teal'
                                    size='sm'
                                    onClick={() => fileUploadHandler()}
                                >
                                    Upload!
                                </Button>
                        }
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h4>Please choose an image to upload</h4>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h4>Choose Photos</h4>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='file' onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])} />
            {fileData()}
            {
                isLoading ?
                    <Spinner /> :
                    <DisplayImage inputImage={inputImage} outputImage={outputImage} />
            }
        </div>
    );
}
export default UploadImage;
```

Comment: nope this doesn't work. It loads spinner at the start.